# Fortran OMP parallel do loop scales differently for gfortran and Intel

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

I abstracted some code from a much larger coding project I'm working on. The code has an OMP parallel do loop which scales well with processor number when compiled with gfortran but badly when compiled with Intel. With gfortran, the code takes 18 seconds to run with 1 processor and 5 seconds to run with 4 processors. With Intel it takes 7 seconds to run with 1 processor and 14 seconds to run with 4 processors. I don't understand what's going on here. The code is below.

```
MODULE test


 TYPE walker

  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: R

 END TYPE walker


 TYPE walkerlist

  INTEGER :: nwlkr 
  TYPE(walker), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: W

 END TYPE walkerlist


CONTAINS


 FUNCTION step( dTau, nelec, ndim ) RESULT ( dR )

  DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN) :: dTau
  INTEGER,   INTENT(IN) :: nelec, ndim
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: dR(ndim,nelec), rand1, rand2, N2DTau
  INTEGER :: d, k
  DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: twopi = 8.d0 * atan(1.d0) 

    N2DTau = -2 * dTau

    DO k = 1, nelec

      DO d = 1, ndim

        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand1)
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rand2)

        dR(d,k) = SQRT( N2DTau * LOG( rand1 ) ) * COS( twopi * rand2 ) 
    
      END DO

    END DO

 END FUNCTION step


END MODULE test


PROGRAM walk

  USE test
  TYPE(walkerlist), TARGET :: Wl
  DOUBLE PRECISION      :: dTau
  INTEGER   :: istp, i, t1, t2, clock_rate, clock_max 

    Wl % nwlkr = 10000 

    ALLOCATE( Wl % W ( Wl % nwlkr ) )

    DO i = 1, Wl % nwlkr

      ALLOCATE( Wl % W(i) % R(3,2) )

    END DO

    dTau = 0.001

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK ( t1, clock_rate, clock_max )


    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED( W ) DEFAULT( FIRSTPRIVATE ) 

    DO i = 1, Wl % nwlkr  

      DO istp = 1, 4000

        Wl % W(i) % R = Wl % W(i) % R + step( dTau, 2, 3 )  

      END DO

    END DO

    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO 


   CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK ( t2, clock_rate, clock_max )

   Print*, "time:", REAL ( t2 - t1 ) / REAL ( clock_rate )

END PROGRAM walk
```

Comment: Please provide compiler versions and compiler command lines used

Comment: You are generating random numbers in the parallel region. In recent versions of gfortran (>8 IIRC), this is supported explicitly by a threaded generator. If that is not the case in ifort, this would explain the big difference: ifort would break out of the parallel processing for each call to `random_number`.

Comment: mpifort –version:
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
The command used was  mpifort  -fopenmp test.f90 

mpiifort –version:
ifort (IFORT) 19.1.0.166 20191121
The command used was  mpiifort  -fopenmp test.f90

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the `random_number` calls, where I'm guessing the threads were sharing seeds. I solved it by instead using the random number generating function `ran`.

```
    rand1 = ran(s)
    rand2 = ran(s)
```

Ran lets you input the seed `s`, which I made thread_private and of the save type. Ran changes the seed only for ifort and not gfortran, so I can't use it for the latter. Ran also sometimes outputs 0, which I personally need to always check for and discard. I also need to Ensure all threads start with a different seed.

Comment: You would be MUCH better off with a dedicated parallel pseudo random number generator. There are several fast ones available. I even doubt `ran()` is thread safe at all - the 0 output is telling.